# SignalR trigger binding for Azure Functions not working (Python)

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-signalr

I wanted to use a SignalR trigger binding with an Azure Function, **so the function is executed everytime a message is sent to the SignalR service** (also running in Azure). I have tried all examples from the Microsoft documentation, and so far no success. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so a bit of help would be appreciated :)

The Function App consists of two parts:

#### Broadcast function

This function is just **sending messages to all clients** connected to the SignalR service periodically (i.e. broadcasting), every 5 seconds.

The function `broadcast/__init__.py` looks like:

```py
import json
import azure.functions as func

def main(myTimer: func.TimerRequest, outMessage: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:

    outMessage.set(json.dumps({
        "target": "newMessage",
        "arguments": ["test"]
    }))
```

Its corresponding `broadcast/function.json` configuration file is:

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "*/5 * * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalR",
      "name": "outMessage",
      "hubName": "testhub",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Trigger function

This function **should be executed every time that a message is sent** to the SignalR service, as explained in the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-trigger?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python):

The code for `trigger/__init__.py` is:

```py
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func

def main(invocation) -> None:
    invocation_json = json.loads(invocation)
    logging.info("Receive {0} from {1}".format(invocation_json['Arguments'][0],
                                               invocation_json['ConnectionId']))
```

And the `trigger/function.json` file looks like:

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "signalRTrigger",
      "name": "invocation",
      "hubName": "testhub",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString",
      "category": "messages",
      "event": "SendMessage",
      "parameterNames": [
          "message"
      ],
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've already set the `AzureSignalRConnectionString` under "Configuration" -> "Application settings" in the Azure Function, and I also added the "Upstream URL pattern" on the SignalR service, [as explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-trigger?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python#signalr-service-integration).

At this point I have tried pretty much every single example I could find, but no success so far. Connecting a JS client works, and the messages can be received, but the trigger function is never executed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!